# GUI frontend for Context mkiv?

Tags: context

Is there any gui frontend/IDE software for ConTeXt MKIV like LyX? What is the status of example framework? Will there be a context document support in jupyter (formerly `ipython`) kernel for graphical editing of context document?

Comment: Seems odd to mention Jupyter here. I assume you mean the Notebook, but doesn't that just use Markdown? And if you're asking for a way to convert a Notebook to ConTeXt code, what you're actually asking if for Pandoc to be able to generate ConTeXt, as `nbconvert` uses Pandoc.

Comment: Can you maybe provide a link for the eXample framework?  I don’t know what it is.

Comment: @HenriMenke Presumably http://wiki.contextgarden.net/XML#eXaMpLe_framework

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks!  Looks like it is for MKII, though.

Comment: @HenriMenke Right, didn't notice that. Perhaps that is part of the reason for asking about it.